# Existence or not of long_double_t (standard C: C23)

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c23

The new standard C (ISO/IEC 9899:2023, aka C23),
in the Annex H, several macros and types are defined,
relative to real and complex arithmetic,
subject to the standard ISO/IEC 60559
(floating-point arithmetic).

According to subsection H.1, there are three
implementation-defined macros to test conformance
with the definitions of Annex H.

```
__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__  
__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__  
__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__
```

In addition, to "activate" the associated macros and types,
the user has to define the macro:

```
__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT__
```

The wording of the standard is clear in several details:

- If `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` is defined by the compiler, it implies that `_FloatN`, `_FloatN_t` and other `_FloatN*` types are defined.
- If `__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__` is defined by the compiler, it implies that `_DecimalN`, `_DecimalN_t` and other `_DecimalN*` types are defined.
- In either case, the macro `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` is defined.
- If the macro `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` is defined, it means that at least one of the macros `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` or `__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__` (or both) is defined.

In subsection H.11, the type `long_double_t` is added to `<math.h>`.

However, I cannot deduce under which conditions one can ensure the existence of `long_double_t` in a given implementation.

**QUESTION:**

If `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` is defined,
is it enough to be sure that `long_double_t` is also defined in `<math.h>`?

My doubt comes from the following particular case that could arise:

- `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` and `__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__` are defined, but `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` is not defined.

In this case, decimal types are defined.
However, `long_double_t` is not a decimal type.

**SUB-QUESTION:**
Is the macro `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` required to exist in order to ensure existence of `long_double_t`?

**COMMENTS:**

As @John Bollinger explains in his answer,
the existence of `*BFP__` and/or `*DFP__` macros
only ensures that `_FloatN` and `_DecimalN` exist
for certain *small* values of `N`.
(I was aware of that detail, but my explanation was not the best.)

[Link to a standard draft of C23](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf)

Comment: Are you asking whether or not the `long_double_t` is actually defined, or if it is different (larger) than an 'ordinary' `double_t`?

Comment: ... because, from my (albeit quick) reading of the linked Standard, the `long_double_t` is now ***required*** but it need only be **at least** as big/precise as `double_t`.

Comment: @AdrianMole: `long_double_t` is a conditional feature, as is part of Annex H of the standard C23, which requires some implementation defined macros to exist. The question is: which macros are enough in order to signal that the implementation has defined `long_double_t` in `<math.h>`?

Comment: Hmm. I was going to post an answer to the effect that checking for a defined `__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT__` should be enough ... but it's not. The presence of that macro definition will only guarantee the `long_double_t` type if it is defined **before** the `#include <math.h>` line in any given TU. That's a tricky thing to test.

Comment: Aside: ISO/IEC 9899:2023 will never exist in the current timeline because 2023 has been and gone without it being published. For example, C17, a.k.a. C18 was finalized in 2017 and published in 2018 as ISO/IEC 9899:2018.

Comment: Suggestion: Use `long double`, which has been standard for a long time, and not a typedef.

Comment: @IanAbbott: You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: the minimum basis for relying on a conforming implementation to provide `long_double_t` is that it defines macro `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` to `202311L`.**

However, *the translation unit* must also define `__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT__` (to anything) before including math.h for the first time for that definition to actually be exposed. (C23 H.8/1)

> The wording of the standard is clear in several details:

Apparently not so clear.

As a preliminary matter, the spec says

> An implementation that defines `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` to `202311L`
> shall conform to the specifications in this annex.

This must be understood to relieve implementations from conforming to anything in the annex if they do not define `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` to that specific value (even if they define it to some other value).  This is an intentional forward-compatibility measure.

The spec goes on to say:

> An implementation may define `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` only if it
> defines `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` [...] or defines `__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__`

Note well that per the previous, neither that provision nor anything else in the annex applies unless `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` is defined to exactly `202311L`.  Otherwise, all bets are off as far as Annex H (of C23) is concerned. For example, an implementation that defined `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` to nothing, and did not define either `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` or `__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__`, would not for that reason fail to conform.

> - If `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` is defined by the compiler, it implies that `_FloatN`, `_FloatN_t` and other `_FloatN*` types are defined.

Not exactly.  The spec does not associate any requirements with an implementation defining `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` alone.  In addition to the general gating by definition of `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__`, discussed above, the spec *explicitly* conditions some of the particular provisions in this area on the latter macro being defined.

When all those conditions are met, a conforming implementation provides types `_Float32` and `_Float64`, and those are equivalent to `float` and `double`, respectively.  Also, under those circumstances, if `long double` corresponds to one of the ISO 60559 binary exchange formats for some width *N* greater than 64, then the implementation provides the corresponding `_FloatN` type as an equivalent to `long double`. Other `_FloatN` types are allowed, but not required, and the set of them is implementation-defined. (H.2.1/4)

A conforming implementation that binds itself to the provisions of this annex provides `_FloatN_t` in its math.h for each `_FloatN` type it provides.

> - If `__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__` is defined by the compiler, it implies that `_DecimalN`, `_DecimalN_t` and other `_DecimalN*` types are defined.

Again, implementations are not bound to anything in the annex unless they define `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` appropriately.  In that case, `__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__` being defined implies that `_Decimal32`, `_Decimal64`, and `_Decimal128` are provided. Additional `_DecimalN` types are explicitly allowed, and that the set of such additional types is implementation defined.

When the provisions of the annex apply at all, math.h will provide a `_DecimalN_t` corresponding to each `_DecimalN` that the implementation defines.

> - In either case, the macro `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` is defined.

No, there is no such requirement.  The logic is the other way around.  As already discussed, none of Annex H applies unless `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` is defined appropriately.  If it is, then at least one of the other two macros must also be defined, but one of those being defined is not a basis for concluding anything about `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__`.

> - If the macro `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` is defined, it means that at least one of the macros `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` or
>   `__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__` (or both) is defined.

More specifically, this applies only if `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` is defined to exactly `202311L`.

---

> If `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` is defined, is it enough to be sure that
> `long_double_t` is also defined in <math.h>?

Macro `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` being defined to exactly `202311L` is enough to be sure that `long_double_t` is available from the implementation.  The annex does not place any additional conditions on that.  The program does need to opt in, however.  C23 H.8/1:

> The identifiers added to library headers by this annex are defined or declared by their respective
> headers only if the macro `__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT__` is defined (by the user) at the
> point in the code where the appropriate header is first included.

You wrote:

> My doubt comes from the following particular case that could arise:
>
> - `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` and `__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__` are defined, but `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` is not defined.
>
> In this case, decimal types are defined.

True.

> However, `long_double_t` is not a decimal type.

Who says? C23 6.2.6.1/1:

> The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.

That subclause does not define the representation of any FP types.

There is no requirement that either `long double` or `long_double_t` be a binary type.  There seems not even to be a requirement that those two types be equivalent, though I would expect that as a quality of implementation matter.

But there is no problem even if `long_double_t` is a binary type. `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` not being defined does not imply that the implementation does not provide any binary FP types.  It means only that the implementation declines to promise that it conforms to all the provisions of Annex H with regard to binary FP types.

> Is the macro `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` required to exist in order to ensure existence of `long_double_t`?

No.  H.11/6 specifies that `long_double_t` is available from math.h, subject to program opt-in as discussed above, and that is not otherwise conditioned on anything other than the same `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` feature test macro on which *everything* in the annex is conditioned.
Thereore, if a conforming implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` to `202311L` then its math.h defines `long_double_t` to those programs that opt in.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. The macro `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` has to exist if some of `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` or `__STDC_IEC_60559_DCP` exist. Read carefully Annex H.1.2(p.2): _An implementation may define __STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__ only
if it defines __STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__, indicating support for IEC 60559 binary floating-point
arithmetic, or defines __STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__, indicating support for IEC 60559 decimal floatingpoint arithmetic (or defines both)._

Comment: @pablo1977, I assure you that I have read the Annex carefully. Look at the *first* sentence of H.1/2.  As this answer already discusses, that must be understood as relieving implementations from conforming to anything in the annex unless they define `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` to `202311L`.  When an implementation does, the next sentence, which you quoted, requires them also to define at least one of the `*BFP__` and `*DFP__` macros.  But when one does not, the next sentence is moot.

Comment: Well John. I still have doubts in the interpretation of that paragraph, but I think that your interpretation might be right. In future versions of the standard the value will be different of `202311L`, and the specifications of all these macros could change.

Comment: Yes, @pablo1977, that is exactly the point of having an overall feature test macro, and of tying the specifications to a particular value for that macro.

Comment: Another comment: I am conscious that the `*BF__` and `DFP__` macros only provide `_FloatN`, N = 32, 64, and `_DecimalN`, N = 32, 64, 128. But I do not wanted to make the question very long. Perhaps my explanation is not correct. On the other hand, I deduce that, if in addition to `*BF__` being defined, one can be sure that `_Float256` exists, say, if `HUGE_VAL_F256` is defined in `<math.h>`.

Comment: No, @pablo1977, the spec does not require that.  Other than `_Float32` and `_Float64` corresponding to `float` and `double`, the only requirement of that kind that annex H places on such an implementation is that *if* `long double` corresponds to an ISO 60559 binary exchange format with width *N* greater than 64, then the implementation must provide `_FloatN`.  There is no analogous requirement for extended FP types, and only a conditional requirement for `long double`.

Comment: John: My assertion is derived from my interpretation of H.11/5 and H.11.1/2, applied to `_Float256` with N = 256. (I am not talking about `long double` or `long_double_t`). I say that, if `**BF__` is defined as already explained, then `_Float256` exists if and only if `HUGE_VAL_F256` exist (for example, or some other macro related to `_Float256`).

Comment: Ah, I see @pablo1977.  I think there is a little bit of weasel room there, but I agree that the best interpretation of the spec is that if an implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__` and `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` as we've discussed, and the program opts in by defining `__STDC_WANT_IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT__` as described, then the implementation's math.h defines macro `HUGE_VAL_F256` if and only if it provides `_Float256` as a floating-point type represented in ISO/IEC 60559 256-bit binary interchange format.

Comment: John. Sorry if a was vague in some parts of my speech. Thank you for your help and patience.